# Best algorithm to remove elements between 2 given indices

Tags: java, c++

So I'm trying to learn algorithm efficiency. I know how to remove one element from the array, but not sure how to remove between two indices. Lets pretend that the 
`list = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`, and we call the `removeBetween` method with arguments: 
`removeBetween(2, 6);`

```
public void removeBetween(int FirstIndex, int LastIndex)
{


}
```

Comment: Are *you* using Java or C++?

Comment: Containers that have indices usually come with an `erase` that does this.

Comment: @upog that's not efficient

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yeah thats not efficient. I'll remove that comment

Comment: I would rather do this in c++ so I can see whats going on, but I would also like to learn to do it in Java, since Java might make it more efficient using there Classes that would do a lot of work for you.

Comment: I will try to do this my self, but would love to see some of you code experts do it more efficiently(faster, less code).

Answer (score 2):

A general algorithmic direction you can follow :

To remove all numbers between 2 given indices, say (FirstIndex, LastIndex):

- Copy all elements from index 0 to FirstIndex to a `result` array.
- Next copy all elements from LastIndex to Array.lenght()-1 indices to the same `result` array above.

Return `result`.

Comment: Of course being careful of whether you want inclusive/exclusive on either side

Comment: Probably the way to go. Use System.arrayCopy() in java, memcpy() in C, and std:copy() in C++ for the highest effeciency

Answer (score 0):

so if you have your items in an array list you can do something like:

```
ArrayList<Whatever object is> newElements = yourlist.sublist( 0, firstIndex );
newElements.addAll( yourlist.subList( LastIndex + 1, yourlist.size() ) ;
```

Comment: OP has an array. You could do create arraylists from the arrays, make the new arraylist, then convert it back to an array. But that doesn't seem like the right way to go.